# How to properly update electron application menu labels?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, menuitem, renderer

I'm trying to add translate support on an electron application, but I've encountered problems when updating the Application menu. I mention that the development is done & tested on macOS, but I'm willing to get it working on Windows too.

I understand that the menu feature is something that can be managed only in the main process, so I'm using ipcMain & ipcRenderer to communicate between the main & renderer process.

The problem is that I'm updating one label, it seems to be updated (shown in logs) but it does not update it in rendered menu.

```js
    //Menu.getApplicationMenu() is in english
    
    mainMenu.language = "nl_nl";
    //updating 1 label
    mainMenu.object.items[0].submenu.items[0].label =i18n.__({phrase: 'Hello', locale: mainMenu.language}),
    
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu.object);
    let currentMenu = Menu.getApplicationMenu();
    //currentMenu reflects the change but the rendered menu still shows the old value (english)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your missing `Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenu.object)`.

To use `Menu.setApplicationMenu(template)` you first need to run `Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenu.object)` on the template to convert it into something `Menu.setApplicationMenu(template)` can pick up.

It would be something like this:

```
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

[Ref.](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/#menubuildfromtemplatetemplate)

Comment: I already have a Menu instance created somewhere up in the code using buildFromTemplate, that's why I'm just setting it, in order to update.

Comment: Well the `.setApplicationMenu` function requires the the template to be run through the `.buildFromTemplate` function first so it would only make sense to run it through even if the menu is already set.

Comment: Apparently, the Menu returned by getApplicationMenu() can not be changed  & updated using setApplicationMenu, but changing the template & building it again works. So you were right. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it worked for you.